# CreateInstance from Type name and Assembly name

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm trying to create a class using `Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName)` but I am getting the error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Could not load type 'Question' from assembly 'AssessmentDeepCompare, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

In this example (which generates the error above) I'm trying to instantiate `Question` which inherits from `IAssessmentObject` and is in the same assembly.

```
public IAssessmentObject getInstance(string typeName) {
    string assemblyName = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof (IAssessmentObject)).ToString();
    return (IAssessmentObject)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName);
}
```

**What is the proper way to instantiate an object when you only have the Type name without the namespace or assembly?**

Comment: So, how Activator should know that you want `X.Foo` instead of `Y.Foo` if you don't tell namespace?

Comment: My suggestion would be to drop Activator and introduce some DI IOC engine into your application. In any case you will need awareness of assembly and of namespace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds like you *do* have the assembly - just not the namespace-qualified type name.

You can fetch *all* the types in the assembly, and get the type from that:

```
var type = typeof(IAssessmentObject).Assembly
                                    .GetTypes()
                                    .Single(t => t.Name == "Question");
var instance = (IAssessmentObject) Activator.CreateInstance(type);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did shortly after I posted the question. Thank you Jon.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the assembly name and the type name, as well as the folder they live in, you can do this.  I built this to return a logging class based on choices in the config file.

```
string _assemblyName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailLogger.AssemblyName"];
string _className = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MailLogger.ClassName"];
string _assemblyPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Reporting.Assembly.Folder"];

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_assemblyName) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(_className))
    throw new ApplicationException("Missing configuration data for the Logger.");

Assembly _loggingAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(System.IO.Path.Combine(_assemblyPath, _assemblyName));
ILogger _logger = _loggingAssembly.CreateInstance(_className) as ILogger;

if (_logger == null)
    throw new ApplicationException(
            string.Format("Unable to instantiate ILogger instance from {0}/{1}", _assemblyName, _className));

return _logger;
```

If you don't have the assembly name, I'm not sure how would create it via reflection.